# How to debug routing issues in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js

When faced with behaviour that does not make sense, it would ideal to able to understand what Next.js is trying to do, rather than blindly keep trying thing till it works.

I searched around for the following questions but came up short:

- Is there a way to increase the server logs produced by Next.js to understand the decisions it is making when routing incoming requests?
- Is there a way to debug and inspect (breakpoints, etc.) what it does with incoming messages?

I note there is a [Debugging](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging) page in the old Page Router but the corresponding page does not exist in the new App Router documentation.

---

The actual problem I am trying to investigate is when I add `src/app/api/xyz/route.ts` (Route handler) to a project that was migrated to 13.x, the server does not seem to recognise it at all. The same project has legacy `src/pages/api/**/*.ts` (API route) files that work just fine. And the `route.ts` file works just fine in a new, empty NextJS 13.x project.

I don't need answer to this particular issue. I rather learn how to fish here. This is frustrating to investigate unless I can see what Next.js router is trying to do here.